# How to deal with order statues when payment method COD and credit/debit card configured?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods, order-status

I have setup payment gateway and cash on delivery as payment methods on my magento site. Here there are two cases for product workflow.

Case 1: When payment is done by credit/debit card.
Order status will change as Order confirmed-> payment received->pending->Invoiced->shipped->completed.

Case 2:
When payment is done using COD method, order status will change as Order confirmed->pending->Invoiced->shipped->Payment pending->payment received->completed.

Can somebody help to setup this workflow in magento.?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with the orders you actually have both `status` and `state`.  `status` is the label you see against the order telling you, well it's status, but the `state` defines what actions can be performed against that order.  You are probably only going to need to use a new `status` as the existing states cover most scenarios.  You can add a new state using a data install script for your module:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

// new status details
$data = array(
    array('status' => 'new_status', 'label' => 'New Status')
);

// add new status to the relevant table
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $installer->getTable('sales/order_status'),
    array('status', 'label'),
    $data
);

// data associating new status with existing state
$data = array(
    array('status' => 'new_status', 'state' => 'holded', 'is_default' => 0)
);

// add association data to the relevant table
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_state'),
    array('status', 'state', 'is_default'),
    $data
);
```

When you have done the above to create each new order status you will probably want to do something along the lines of use save observers on invoice/shipment creation to modify the order state.  You can do this very simply once you have the order object using:

```
$order->setState($state, $status, $comment, $notifycustomer)->save();
```

`$state` should be the order state, `$status` is optional and can be the new `status` you created, but it can also be `true` to use the default `status` for the `state`.  `$comment` is optional and should be any comment you want to add to the order, and `$notifycustomer` is optional and should be `true` or `false` (default) according to whether you want to notify the customer about the `status` change.

Comment: @jonathan-hussay I have add a new order status using Adminpanel > System> Order staus> Create new status. And apply that status to Order state using Order Status>Assign Status to State. Coding suggested by you also doing the same thing but programming way. But I can not control the workflow of orders. e.g. See the workflow for this link. [link](http://iamvikram.com/magento-orders-states-and-statuses/). How can I edit this complete magento workflow of any orders with above two cases mentioned in my question?